# An object disappears when I start the game engine. How do I fix this?

Tags: game-engine, objects

I am working on a game, and one particular object disappears when I press "P" to start the game engine. The scene this problem is occurring in was copied from another scene, and this problem didn't happen in the original scene that I copied from. Changing the normals had no effect, invisibility is turned off in the physics, and this object has no keyframes. All the other objects in the scene are visible. I am using version 2.69 of Blender. Any solutions you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uncheck restrict rendering in the outliner.

Comment: A typical cause: * one of the objects parents is not present

Comment: If the object is a plane, make sure you are rendering the back face in the materials tab.

Answer (score 1):

The object might be located somewhere else. So it is not visible to the camera.

Check the existence and the location with this code:

```
import bge

name = "Cube"

object = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects[name]
print("Object", object.name, "is at", object.worldPosition)
```